# Selecting right transaction with ADO Ms Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ado

I have a program and:

1. Create a table named table1. Now [database1].table1 is empty.
2. Start my program. My program calls Ado Connection object's BeginTrans method.
3. My program does time consuming number of inserts on [database1].table1 via AdoQuery.
4. My program calls Ado Connection object's CommitTrans method.

If I start the program, then issue `select * from table1` query on Management Studio, the query does not return until my program is finished.

I want to see an empty resultset without waiting when issue select query on Management Studio.
Which transaction should I use and how can I configure it with ADO programmatically ?

**Edits:**

As far as I googled, I may select one of the Repeatable Read, Snapshot or Serializable isolation levels and/or optimistic lock. I make some test and answer my question depending on test results.

Edit after Doug_Ivison 's comment:
In my situation, another closed source software uses the tables instead of Management Studio. And we are trying some kind of replication (Sorry for missing detail, I was trying to keep question shorter).

Thank you for reading my post.
Regards
Ömür Ölmez.

Comment: It may be simple resource contention--I've seen that happen--even without locking conflicts.  But if you think avoiding locking is worth a try, then another option is `select * from table1 with(nolock)`

Comment: @Doug_Ivison, thank you for your help. I am sorry I preferred to keep text shorter. In my situation, since another closed source software make the second select query, I have no chance to use select with lock, dirty read isolation and some other solutions.

Comment: Note that if the "closed source software" is determining a query against `table1`, you can create a `view` named `table1`.... and then the software would read your view, whenever it tried to read that table.  That way, you could add `with(nolock)` or whatever else you want, to the query... as long as your view creates an exactly matching columnlist, as output.